# SetVariable is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have implemented a web page with Flash Player. And then I have used `SetVariable` keyword to give a param for a flash player object.

```
document.getElementById('flashPlayer').SetVariable("player.jsUrl","www.my.com/Songs/a.mp3");
```

It is working finely in IE and Chrome except Firefox. Which keyword is working concern it in Firefox?

P.S The error is "Error calling method on NPObject!".

Comment: have you installed Flash Player Debug...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox can only use this function on the `embed` element, not the `object` element.

#### HTML

```
<object id="flashPlayer">
    <embed id="flashPlayerEmbed">
</object>
```

#### Javascript

```
var player = document.getElementById('flashPlayer');

if(typeof(player.SetVariable) == 'undefined') {
   player = document.getElementById('flashPlayerEmbed');
}

player.SetVariable("plyaer.jsUrl", "www.my.com/Songs/a.mp3");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is caused when trying to call the **SetVariable** call before the swf is loaded. 
Try something like this:

```
function someTest() {
 ....
 document.getElementById('flashPlayer').SetVariable("player.jsUrl","www.my.com/Songs/a.mp3");
}
```

And onload on body

```
<body onload="setTimeout('someTest();',500);">
```

Hope it helps